# Name of a set of the form {x,y}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I know that a doubleton is a set with exactly two elements, but what is the name of a set with either exactly 1 element or exactly 2 elements? In other words, what is the name of a set of the form {x,y}. A name for this concept would allow much easier and shorter definitions of some mathematical terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an accepted single word doesn't exist. "Doubleton" and "pair" both indicate two element sets to me; even clearly defining your usage would probably lead to confusing for people skimming.

So, I'll suggest "spair" (concatenating "singleton" and "pair"). It's at least currently unused (AFAIK) and short, though it sounds a bit silly.

Comment: I agree. "Spair" it is.

Comment: Add my vote for Spair.

Answer (score 2):

*A set with no more than two elements*

If you want to exclude the empty set then
*a non-empty set with no more than two elements*

Comment: That is a rather long phrase to say.

Comment: A concise one-word term would be better.

Comment: @user107952 What is the hurry?  If you understand it, you can use whatever word you like.  If you want somebody else to understand it, why not take the time to just say what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Unordered pair. Or just pair.

The name sort of implies that the two elements are distinct, but it's not necessary. I'd still add a remark along the lines of "note we do not require $x\neq y$" nearby the definition of the term.

Answer (score 0):

I have occasionally heard of the form $\{x\}$ being called "singletons".

So… "doubletons"? It's definitely not standard, but you'll probably be understood more than half the time.

Also, I'm not sure I agree with the premise that "it would allow much easier and shorter definitions of some mathematical terms". The only thing that comes to mind is the naive definition of graphs.